# What kind of [legacy] are we leaving here?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Stumbled across these two tags while cleaning up the [intellij-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-plugin) tag:

- [legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legacy)
- [legacy-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legacy-app)

I could see legacy-app going away altogether - it's 12 questions and for the most part, the application-specific tags provide enough context into the question such that it doesn't need to be prefaced with it.

[legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legacy) is a bit trickier; there's over 450 questions with it.  This one's kind of up in the air.

Thoughts?  Burnination?

Comment: [tag:legacy-app] should go for sure, it can always be rolled into [tag:legacy]. You are right that the other one is more difficult, and it depends on how it is actually used/promoted: Anything which is old, meaning all older questions should, earlier or later, be tagged with it? Burn it with fire then. Special problems which happen due to bridging the gap between old and new systems? Not sure about that, but probably retag [tag:integration], [tag:migration], [tag:interop], or better yet [tag:untagged], depending on what exactly is asked.